# SQL Server: Sanitizing @param against injection attacks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection

For the sake of argument, let's just say I **have to** create a local variable containing a SQL query that has an INSERT:

```
 DECLARE @insert NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SELECT @insert = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[' + @table + '] VALUES...
 EXEC (@insert)
```

This INSERT is also going to contain a column value:

```
 DECLARE @insert NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SELECT @insert = 
  'INSERT INTO [dbo].[' + @table + '] VALUES (N''' + @message + ''')'
 EXEC (@insert)
```

Now, I'm obviously concerned about an injection attack, and would like to ensure that @message's value can't make @insert's value malicious or malformed as a query to EXEC.

This brings us to my question: is escaping the ' characters in @message sufficient? Are there any other characters that could appear in @message that could escape out?

Example:

```
 DECLARE @insert NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SELECT @message = REPLACE(@message,'''','''''')
 SELECT @insert = 
  'INSERT INTO [dbo].[' + @table + '] VALUES (N''' + @message + ''')'
 EXEC (@insert)
```

(When I say "**have to**", this is because my query is in a stored procedure, and this stored procedure accepts @table, which is the destination table to INSERT into. I'm not interested in discussing my architecture or why the table to INSERT into is "dynamically" specified via a procedure parameter. Please refrain from commenting on this *unless there's another way besides EXEC()ing a query to specify a table to INSERT into when then table name is received as a procedure parameter*.)

Comment: Do we really want to deal with questions that deal with how to intentionally write bad code?

Comment: If it means finding a solution, yes. Developers have to deal with crap code all the time, especially if you do consulting and inherit projects written in Bangladesh for $8/hr. We don't always get the luxury of building projects from scratch, building them the way they should *have* been. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `sp_executesql` and the built-in `quotename()`. This article, [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), is pretty much the definitive reference.

Comment: Apparently there's a 128-length limit to quotename(), even in 2008, since it expects a SQL identifier. The reference suggests creating a quotestring() function (http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#quotestring), which does exactly the same thing as REPLACE(@variable,'''','''''').

Answer (score 2):

Rather than calling EXEC(@somesql), I suggest using the [sp_executesql stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).  Specifically, this allows you to pass parameters, and the system will check that the parameters are valid.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, SQL Server 2008 Express is telling me "Must declare the table variable '@my_table'." after executing that code.

Comment: I was sure I did this in SQL Server 2005, but I admit that I could just be very very tired.  I apologize.  I'll try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You could first query the schema information with regular T-SQL and make sure the table name exists first. This way, if it's malformed SQL, it won't execute as code. It will just be a VARCHAR table name.

```
DECLARE @Table AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Exists AS BIT

SET @Table = 'Vicious malformed dynamic SQL'

SELECT  @Exists = COUNT(TABLE_NAME) 
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE   TABLE_NAME = @Table

IF (@Exists = 1)
    BEGIN
    PRINT 'Table exists'
    -- Execute dynamic SQL.
    END
ELSE
    PRINT 'Invalid table'
```

(Or simply use IF EXISTS (SELECT ....) )

Comment: Good thinking. I've been doing what follows. Is there any advantage of either? What I've been doing: "IF OBJECT_ID(@table,'U') IS NULL..."

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's a 128-length limit to quotename(), even in 2008 according to my test, since it expects a SQL identifier. The reference suggests creating a [quotestring()](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#quotestring%20) function, which does the same thing as:

```
REPLACE(@variable,'''','''''')
```

Therefore I am proposing that the answer is to create a function out of the REPLACE() above, like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION quotestring(@string nvarchar(MAX)) 
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    RETURN(REPLACE(@string,'''',''''''))
END
```

...Unless I've misunderstood something.

Comment: Can you pass an nvarchar(MAX) as a parameter like that?

Comment: Sure, why not? It's now an operating function in my dev. environment. :)

Answer (score 0):

When writing dynamic SQL you'll want to parameterise as much as possible, and only resort to character escaping when you absolutely have to. You can't parameterise @table, but you can parameterise @message.

```
DECLARE @insert NVARCHAR(MAX)
set @insert = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].' + quotename(@table) + ' values(@message)'
exec sys.sp_executesql @insert, N'@message nvarchar(max)', @message = @inMessage;
```

There are a lot of ways attackers can exploit dynamic SQL, including buffer length attacks and using unicode equivalent characters. I encountered an example once where escaping the single quote char still had a vulnerability where one of the unicode equivalents of the quote char could be passed in. Part of the software stack was doing a unicode to ascii conversion, so it was possible to inject a quote back in after they were escaped. Ouch.