# How to pass the table name and the selected fields as parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, informix, parameterized-query

I get the following error :

> ERROR:-201
>   MEssage: [Informix .NET provider][Informix]A syntax error has occurred.

when I try to execute this code  :

```
string table_name = resultDt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
string pdf_column = resultDt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
st.Append(" SELECT  ? FROM ?");
paramList.Clear();
paramList.Add("@tablename", table_name);
paramList.Add("@pdf_column", pdf_column);
resultDt =dalHelper.Return_DataTable(st.ToString(), CommandType.Text, paramList);
return resultDt;
```

Comment: Why not use like `"SELECT " + pdf_column + " FROM " + table_name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Use String.Replace instead.

```
st.Append(" SELECT @pdf_column FROM @tablename");
st.Replace("@tablename", table_name);
st.Replace("@pdf_column", pdf_column);
```

If table_name and pdf_column comes from user input in anyway you should use a QuoteName function (i.e. `QuoteName(table_name)`) to prevent sql injection. Don't know about Informix but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513052/157224) is one for SqlServer.

Comment: It is for any database. The sql statement contains column and table before it is sent to the database

Comment: You can only use placeholders for values, not for structural elements of a query such as table names or column names.